# Phonegap: Error creating ios sub-project on Windows

Tags: cordova, npm

I manage to create a new phonegap project and add the android platform successfully with the following command:

```
cordova platform add android
```

But when i try to add the ios platform the error:

```
'"C:\Users\ryan.pays\.cordova\lib\ios\cordova\3.3.0\bin\create"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

    at C:\Users\ryan.pays\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\platform.js:282:30
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:948:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

I went into C:\Users\myusername.cordova\lib and deleted the ios folder to try again but still i get the same error.

Am using the latest on phonegap, cordova and plugman.

Any ideas as to what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot develop the ios platform in Windows, you need a Mac system.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: I realised that I am an idiot for asking soon after asking. Thanks!